# How to determine a frequency of maven dependency usage in a project

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-plugin

Let's say we have an application that pulls in two different dependencies in order to check if a String is null or empty. If the majority of the application is using dependency A for checking the String is Empty and only one class is leveraging dependency B, I want to remove dependency B and migrate the code to leverage dependency A. Is there a library or some automatic analysis that can tell me how much a dependency is used within a project?